# Recieving same notification after logging out with react-native-firebase

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, firebase-notifications, react-native-firebase

I am trying to implement push notifications with react-native and react-native-firebase. 
I used the following tutorial

https://medium.com/@anum.amin/react-native-integrating-push-notifications-using-fcm-349fff071591

But when the notification is recieved in the background. Clicking on that leads me to open the app. 
If I logout and login back again. it shows me the same notification again.

```
class NotificationListener extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
    this.createNotificationListeners();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.notificationListener();
        this.notificationOpenedListener();
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/sort-comp
    async createNotificationListeners() {
        // Triggered when a particular notification has been received in foreground
        this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
            console.log('------NOTIFICATION1------------');
            console.log(notification);
            let { _data } = notification;
            if (_data && _data.Action) {
                this.notificationDirect(_data);
            }
        });

        // If your app is in background, you can listen for when a notification is clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
        this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
            console.log('------NOTIFICATION2------------');
            console.log(notificationOpen.notification);
            let { _data } = notificationOpen.notification;
            if (_data && _data.Action) {
                this.notificationDirect(_data);
            }
        });

        /*
                * If your app is closed, you can check if it was opened by a notification being clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
                * */
        const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
        if (notificationOpen) {
        // debugger;
            console.log('------NOTIFICATION3------------');
            console.log('---- NOTIFICATION WHEN APP IN BACKGROUND OR CLOSED------');
            console.log(notificationOpen.notification);
            let { _data } = notificationOpen.notification;
            if (_data && _data.Action) {
                this.notificationDirect(_data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: It is quite a big tutorial to read for some one to understand what exactly you did to create the notification. Please add some code here about how you handled the notification opening thing. You might need to discard that once it is opened!! but that is just a guess.

Comment: added the code. please check

Comment: You can cancel all local notifications while logging out. Something like `PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications`

Comment: I tried cancelling the notification using firebase.notifications().cancelNotification(notificationOpen.notification.notificationId); But it didnt work.

Comment: where did you put this code. In the log out event ? What did you get ? an error ?

Comment: even if i reload the app while debugging, i am getting the notitication.